# tool for soap web servcie client, that can take credentials and give inputs

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have written a Web services that has authentication to it. It need username and password. It is soap based one. It need string input to it.

Can any one suggest the soap client which satisfies above requirements.

I tried with default web service launcher in eclipse, but it does not seem to take credentials.

Even plugin for eclipse would be fine

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/)

its a wonderful tool for testing all sorts of webservices

*SoapUI provides complete test coverage - from SOAP and REST-based Web services, to JMS enterprise messaging layers, databases, Rich Internet Applications, and much more.*

Comment: you can use it standalone or as a plugin in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a testing client for SOAP, I'd immediately think of [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/).

If you mean writing your own client for use in your code, I'd find a tutorial to show you how to pass credentials.  Or try Spring web services - it has a very nice SOAP client.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can we get SOAP UI installation as ZIP. Because I dont have admin rights to install it.

Comment: Nope, I just see an installer.